# How to add this JSON to spinner and get item of spinner

Tags: json, android-spinner, getjson

here is my Json:

> { 1: "Nam" 2: "Nữ" 3: "Khác" } >

Comment: are you sure it is exact json response? It seems response is not valid json.
May be response will
{ "Nam":1, "Nữ":2, "Khác":3 }

Comment: { 1: "Nam" 2: "Nữ" 3: "Khác" }